# Не отображать одну запись в wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Есть сайт на wordpress, на главной странице лентой отображаются несколько записей, которые не хочется смещать (и вообще трогать). В настройках записей есть всякие стили отображения(в настройках страниц ничего такого нет), хочется добавить несколько записей, но чтоб они не отображались на главной, а просто добавить ссылки в тексте и в виджетах на эти записи. 
Можно ли так сделать?

Answer (score 1):

/* фильтр скрытых рубрик*/
/*разместить в function.php , -10 -11 скрытые рубрики*/

```
function hidecategory($query) {
    if ( $query->is_home ) {
        $query->set('cat','-10,-11');
    }
return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'hidecategory');
```